# Does "I don't think I'm any more [adjective]" mean "I'm not [adjective]"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

https://youtu.be/-qfI3DZmmQw?t=42

> It’s not like there’s a shortage of scientific facts out there spelling it all out for us.
>
> But let’s be honest — not many people can relate to scientists sharing their data, no matter how compelling it is.
>
> When I give talks as a scientist versus when I’m talking to a friend, I don’t think I’m **any more** persuasive. In fact, I think as a scientist, I may be actually less trusted.

I guess here he's saying like "I'm not very persuasive",
but I'm not familiar with this usage (I'm only used to expressions like "I don't do that **any more**.")
and don't exactly know what this sentence means.

Does "I don't think I'm any more [adjective]" mean "I'm not [adjective]"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***More*** indicates a comparison. "I'm not any **more** [adjective]" cannot stand alone and be meaningful - some context must indicate what is being compared to what. The ***any*** just indicates that the *not more* is absolute. So:

> I don't think I'm any more persuasive than you

Means the speaker doesn't think they are even slightly more persuasive than the person they are addressing.

> I don't think I'm much more intelligent than Bob

Means the speaker acknowledges that they may be more intelligent than Bob, but they don't think it's to a large degree.

The comparison in your example is about talking in different roles:

> **When I give talks as a scientist** versus **when I’m talking to a friend**, I don’t think I’m any more persuasive. In fact, I think as a scientist, **I may be actually less trusted**.

They are saying that they are no more persuasive when being a scientist, giving talks, than they are when they are just talking to friends. They then go on to say that they may be *less* persuasive in that situation - using *trusted* as an alternative to *persuasive*, which I see problems with, but that's a whole other kettle of fish.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, this:

> I don’t think I’m any more persuasive.

should be understood in this way:

- **"I don't think I'm..."** = (I assume / I guess / I estimate) I am not...
- **"more persuasive"** = standard meaning, no tricks
- **"any"** = is used near "more" to indicate a (relatively) small "quantity"

So overall meaning could be understood something like this:

> I guess I am not more persuasive, not more than a little bit.

Regarding this:

> Does "I don't think I'm any more [adjective]" mean "I'm not [adjective]"?

The answer is "yes and no". While base meaning is similar, the sentence with "I don't think" implies some level of uncertainty, while "I'm not" implies certain knowledge.

The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/any) may help in more detail explaining the meanings of "any".

Comment: So he's saying "Compared to when talking to an audience as a scientist and when talking to a friend, there's no difference in persuasiveness"?

Comment: So "any" here is like "not even a bit"?

Comment: You helped me find a better wording, see edit. Here, "any" is more similar to "just a little bit". This is not exact science, of course, and a perfect synonym may not exist. But you got the general idea. One thought: "any" actually does not have the purpose to specify "quantity", but to introduce some ambiguity, same as "I think".